# Impose max combined file size for file inputs through jQuery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an interesting scenario at hand, however I'm not well versed with jQuery validate at the moment.

**GOAL:** Using the FileAPI, determine the file size of each file to be uploaded in multiple `<input type="file" />` controls while also using the jQuery validate plugin, ensuring that the combined total of bytes is not greater than 50Mb. These elements can be dynamically added/deleted.

For the sake of consistency, I'd like this validation to work through the jQuery validator plugin, where the error message will be appended under the last input file control.

From what I understand, adding a method to the validator only verifies one element at a time, so I guess first question, can a single method validate MULTIPLE elements once as opposed to being fired for each element.

Ex.:

`<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />`

`<input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />`

`<input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Add rule to all elements when document is ready
        $('input[type="file"]').rules("add", {
            totalFileSize: true
        });
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("totalFileSize", function(value, element) {

        // Even if there's 3 input elements, this should only fire once and, 
        // if totalFileSize > 50Mb, then display error under the last input element

    }, "Total file size too large");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand, adding a method to the validator only verifies one element at a time, so I guess first question, can a single method validate MULTIPLE elements once as opposed to being fired for each element.

Yes, each element is verified by itself against each rule declared upon it.

<s>No, a single method cannot validate multiple elements at once.  The rule/method is declared on each element and then each of these elements are validated against it one at a time.</s>

Edit:  I forgot about the `skip_or_fill_minimum` and the `require_from_group` rules that are part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).  These rules are examples of methods that can evaluate several fields at once.  The rule must be declared on each field considered for evaluation, and [the `groups` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#groups) is then used to condense the duplicate messages into one.

Play around with it here:  [jsfiddle.net/r32vbm8j/](http://jsfiddle.net/r32vbm8j/)

However, these two example rules are fired when the submit button is clicked.  In that case, it's **not** fired once... but fired on each declared field, same as all other rules on the form.

---

You cannot do this...

```
$('input[type="file"]').rules("add", {
    totalFileSize: true
});
```

Since the `$('input[type="file"]')` selector can represent multiple elements, only the first matching element is attached to `.rules()`, and the other matching elements are ignored.

To attach `.rules()` to multiple elements requires iteration using a jQuery `.each()`.

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        totalFileSize: true
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT**:

> The only problem in the end is that `groups` will display all rules assigned to an individual element at a single unified point, whereas I would need to display that one error message for x number of elements while also retaining all other error messages assigned to their respective elements. End result is that I want each of the file inputs to display "File cannot exceed 10MB" as an error message, but have a second validation that checks the sum of all the sizes, "Sum of files cannot exceed 50MB" however that one error message should be singled out, as not to be needlessly repeated.

1. Employ [the `showErrors` callback function](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors).  This will suppress all individual error messages as long as you leave out the `this.defaultShowErrors()` line.
2. Within the `showErrors` function you have access to the following arguments where you can construct your own consolidated or individual messages as you see fit.

`errorMap` - Key/value pairs, where the key refers to the name of an input field, values the message to be displayed for that input.

`errorList` - An array for all currently validated elements. Contains objects with the following two properties:  `message` and `element`.

```
$('form').validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // parse and display messages as needed
    },
    ....
```

Comment: Actually, if there's a way to set the errorPlacement from within the addMethod function, then that could potentially work? Therefore I'd validate the size for each input, but only display the error at the bottom of the :last-child element

Comment: Quote @MPaul: *"if there's a way to set the `errorPlacement` from within the addMethod function..."* ~ That is impossible.  `errorPlacement` is an option set within the `.validate()` method and it is generically triggered by any rule.   However, if you simply want to lump the messages together into one, then use the `groups` option.  Again, `groups` will lump together all messages from all rules for the assigned fields.

Comment: That seems like it would work, however by adding the `groups` option won't it group any other `rules` assigned to those elements as well?

Comment: @MPaul, intended for use with a rule that produces the same message on multiple fields, but the `groups` options does not care.   The `groups` option will take the messages from the declared fields and replace them all with one message.  It does not matter which rules are used, you'll still get one message.  So if you have different rules on different fields and use `groups` on them all, you will get a single unpredictable message.

Comment: @MPaul, play around:  http://jsfiddle.net/r32vbm8j/  ~ replace the words *"single unpredictable message"* in my last comment with the words *"single message representing the current error"*.

Comment: The only problem in the end is that `groups` will display all rules assigned to an individual element at a single unified point, whereas I would need to display that one error message for **x** number of elements while also retaining all other error messages assigned to their respective elements. 

End result is that I want each of the file inputs to display "File cannot exceed 10MB" as an error message, but have a second validation that checks the sum of all the sizes, "Sum of files cannot exceed 50MB" however that one error message should be singled out, as not to be needlessly repeated.

Comment: @MPaul, you could also use the `showErrors` callback.  By default it will suppress all individual form validation errors (leave out `this.defaultShowErrors()` line).   Then you can write a custom function to construct the error message you need.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors   It's also possible that your desired functionality is impossible to achieve with this plugin.

Comment: that's interesting, I'll take a look into that. Perhaps I can display all errors by default except my specific singled out error, in which case I can simply assign the error directly to a span element after the last file input. However won't I need to write custom code in the errorPlacement as well so I don't display the error twice, assuming I manually display the error in the showErrors callback?

Comment: If you put `this.defaultShowErrors()` within `showErrors`, then you'll get the default error message next to every input as per default or `errorPlacement`.  If you do **not** put `this.defaultShowErrors()` within `showErrors`, then you will **not** get any message next to any input and `errorPlacement` will not matter.